# One to one and Groupchat in Android App

Tags: android, chat

I am newer to Android but am trying to add a chat feature within my application. In terms of areas I have tried they include pre-built systems such as Quickblox and Scringo, but each are highly inflexible and also require employing their user authentication sources as well, which are not needed.

Is there a general location for resources to build a chat feature that will also persist past messages for viewing as well? Or suggested services that could help handle sending messages?

(Any guidance is greatly appreciated)